# Sequelize ORM doesn't read numeric value 9xxxxxxx9.0000000000 properly

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize ORM in NodeJs to connect to MSSQL server.
Recently I encountered an issue where one particular value gets represented differently when read via sequelize. That value is `9xxxxxxx9.0000000000`

Ex: Suppose the value is `999999999.0000000000`
When read via sequelize the value which comes is 999999999.0000001
In Sequelize the model has type `DataTypes.INTEGER` and `allowNull` is true

I have created bug to Sequelize as well but it will be great if somebody can help me here as well. 
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11131

I have tried with many versions of Sequelize including the latest one, but the issue persists. I tried with different set of values, like eight times 9 and it returns the value properly. The issue comes only when the number of digits are nine and number starts and ends with number 9.

Sequelize Model in NodeJS

```
function getModel(dBSequelize, DataTypes) {
    const model = dBSequelize.define(
        'testtable',
        // attributes
        {
            Id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            Quantity: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull: true
            }
        },
        // options
        {
            schema: 'dbo',
            freezeTableName: true,
            tableName: 'TestTable',
            timestamps: false
        });

    return model;
}

module.exports = getModel;
```

Reading value using sequelize

```
    async getData(context) {
        try {
            const connection = await dbFactory.getTediousConnection();
            var query = "select Quantity from dbo.[TestTable]"

            const response = await connection.execSql(query);
            connection.close();

            return response;
        }
        catch (error) {
        }
    }
```

What do you expect to happen?
999999999

What is actually happening?
999999999.0000001

Comment: Per your linked issue, though, the data type is *not* an integer, it's a `DECIMAL(28, 10)`, so at the very least you're asking for a conversion you're better off performing in the database itself (`select convert(int, quantity) as quantity`). The problem is not in Sequelize but in Tedious, specifically [this](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/blob/f2ce6aa6b141e8ff1dc855b58d16b457c006d652/src/value-parser.js#L302). It calculates `9999999990000000000 / Math.pow(10, 10)`, the result of which is not precisely `999999999`. JavaScript is not a good language for exact numerics.

Comment: "Fixing" this issue, in the sense of demanding that Tedious at least convert every value that has an exact representation precisely (and `999999999` does have an exact representation as a `Number`) is possible in theory, but not particularly simple. This would also not really fix the issue for values that would fit in a `DECIMAL(28, 10)`, but have no exact representation as a `Number` (like `999999999.0000000001`), so it would at best mask the real problem (that we're not using a true base 10 type).

Comment: I suppose a "fix" to Sequelize could also be considered where, despite the underlying data, it will convert numeric values to the specified data model "type" by rounding them to the nearest integral value. This also is not a perfect fix in all circumstances because of the inherent trouble you invite with implicit rounding -- should `999999999.5` then become `999999999` or `1000000000`? It would, however, fix it if you consistently access a `DECIMAL` through an `INT` lens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jeroen. We converted the value in a string while fetching it from db and parsed into float. It works for us as after decimal four values will be sufficient for us.

select convert(varchar, Quantity) as Quantity....

Quantity = parseFloat(Quantity)